# Is there a "easy" way to extract the dom structure of html element without using a python libary?

Tags: python, html, dom

So far as I know BeautifulSoup and lxml are able to extract the dom structure of html element. But I would like to do it by myself because I need a high performance crawler without libary limitations. So

Is there a "easy" way to extract the dom structure of html element without using a python libary?

I ask this because I want to find a html element by only searching in the frontend of a website and then after I know which element I want then I need the dom path of this element.

For example the DOM path of the stackoverflow logo on this page is:

```
html > body.ask-page.new-topbar > div.container > div#header > div#logo > a
```

Comment: You need *something* that implements the [HTML5 parser algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parsing).  You certainly *could* implement that yourself in a higher-performance language than Python, providing exactly the API you want, and then wrap it into Python, but it would be an awful lot of work...

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a context-free grammar and there is no guarantee that a given HTML response will be valid XML-wise (eg a clear tag hierarchy and everything having matching closing tags). The document structure is partially guessed by browsers and partially created using specific rules, if the tags are all messed up and not in a hierarchy.

If you really want to write your own HTML parsing library, and your example is *not* limited to a very specific kind of text you want to match (so a crude regex will not help), then consider the following HTML snippets that you can try and figure out the DOM structure for:

Let's start off with `<p>` guessing:

```
<p>blah blah
<p>blah blah
<p>blah blah
<p>blah blah <img src="a.jpg"> <!-- where is this image? -->
```

How about malformed closing tag order?

```
<a href="test.html"><img src="a.jpg"> <b>this is a cool image </a></b>
```

What about nesting wrong content types together?

```
<p>blah blah <div class="button"><img src="derp.png"></div></p>
```

In this example the `<p>` is closed before the `<div>` starts, because `<p>` does not accept [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) in it.

However, libraries like beautifulsoup are already equipped to parse all these terrible contraptions and more.